# How to check for custom url scheme on iphone?

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

I want to use custom url schemes in my app, for example calling navigons mobile navigator.
First of all I want to check whether navigon is installed or at least whether the custom url scheme "navigon://" has already been registered.

Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at UIApplication's

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

Comment: Ouuh nice, I didn't think it was so easy.  Shame on me.
Thanks a lot!