# Require install of second app in iOS

Tags: android, iphone, ios, deployment

I have a 'core' app which performs some functions which are available to other apps via a URL call, e.g. core://get_result     [as per this: http://x-callback-url.com/examples/ ]

I want to allow 3rd parties to develop by calling my core, or to produce more elaborate apps myself which call the core from within a wrapper.   We have developed and tested this approach.

I want to use this approach because:

- we don't want to expose our core code to 3rd party developers
- we don't want users who install multiple apps that use the same core to have multiple huge downloads (rather than 1 big core and several smaller wrappers)
- we want to keep tight control on the content in the core (for regulatory reasons) but are more relaxed about the wrapper
- we stop people tweaking the core code this way
- potentially we can open this to 'designers' using HTML5 rather than developers too...

I am initially interested in iOS but a similar question will arise on Android (although possible via intents rather than the url scheme).

The downside of this seems to be that the user has to install BOTH apps to get the functionality.  **is there a way of forcing the user to download the core app if they try to install a wrapper that uses it?**

Another minor gripe might be that downloading only the core puts an icon on the phone - when really the user probably doesn't ever want to use the core directly.  **Is there a way to hide it?**

Comment: I understand if you want third parties to be able to use it, it should be a separate app, but if you need it in your own app, why not just add the functionality in rather than calling outside? This gives you an advantage over third party apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for custom url scheme on iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716508/how-to-check-for-custom-url-scheme-on-iphone)

Comment: @MarcusAdams thanks - that is possibly part of the solution but it is not quite the same "problem statement" (or I'd have found it!).  We believe there are good reasons for this approach (not least that revision to the "core" requires a convoluted, expensive and time consuming approval process but the wrappers (of which there may be several around the same core) are somewhat simpler to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can detect if your other URL handler is registered and if it isn't, you can prompt users to download that app. No, you can not hide it.

I am not sure how Apple reviewers will feel about this though. You might want to check the TOS / Guidelines. Also, you can register all the apps under the same suite.

Comment: thanks - when you say detect URL handler is that done at install time or when you try to call the URL handler/run the app?  Ideally you want the user to discover the need for the core app at the time they are connected to the internet / app store, not several hours later when they go to use the app and have no/poor signal.   I don't see anything explicitly banning this - and they allow URL schemes to be registered so its a logical approach.

Comment: there is no concept of userland install time. Youd have to do it at applicaiton launch. Basically you have no ability to know anything via the app until the user launches it.