# Detecting Apps on iPad through bundle indentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to print all the apps installed on iPad which are not published on the app store.Means I know the bundle identifier of my apps and I want to check through the code if they are installed on my iPad or not.

Keep it in mind that my device is *not* jailbroken.

Comment: @dandan78  my device is not jailbroken ... so remove the duplication

Comment: @Rob Napier code works for only jailbroken devices ....

Comment: I just nominated this question to be reopened. This question is specifically for iOS devices that have not been jailbroken. The question and answers referenced by the close vote are for jailbroken devices.

Comment: @Farrukh : are you planning such app to put on app store?

Comment: @FahimParkar no just want to do for my self.. I have  some other use.

Comment: @Farrukh : how about [iHasApp](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp)

Comment: @FahimParkar i have used this api ... but it lists only those apps which are published on the app store.  :(

Comment: @FahimParkar my concern is to list  my own apps which are not published on the app store.

Comment: @Farrukh Next time, do include such relevant pieces of information in your question. One way that this can be done is to install a custom URI scheme for your app, then do something like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716508/how-to-check-for-custom-url-scheme-on-iphone) to see if it is registered, thereby indirectly confirming that the registering app is installed.

Comment: @dandan78 ok , next time I'll take care of it.

Comment: @dandan78 please help me to understand , how can I install custom URI scheme for my app ?

Comment: @dandan78 thanks for your suggestion.It worked for me.I have added custom URL scheme for my app.

Comment: @dandan78 is it possible to find out the version of installed app on ios device?